# Program to read from user and then stop

Tags: java

Program to read from user and then stop

I am trying to write a program for a homework that reads fruit name, price and kilograms from the user then prints out each fruit entered with its price, kilograms and total price.
What I cannot do is to make it read until the user inputs "stop" then it stops and gives the above calculation.
I've done the following so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // importing class scanner
public class Q2 { // class declaration
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int Price;
int Kilograms;
int sum;
int fruit;

System.out.print("Enter Price here  ");//prompt
Price = input.nextInt();// 

System.out.print("Enter Kilograms here  ");//prompt
Kilograms = input.nextInt();

 sum = Price * Kilograms;

System.out.printf("Total price is %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: Search for do / while structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your objective you have to use do/while loop.

**Example:**

```
String exit;
double sum;
do{
    System.out.print("Enter Price here  ");//prompt
    Price = input.nextInt();// 

    System.out.print("Enter Kilograms here  ");//prompt
    Kilograms = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter "stop" to stop iteration");
    exit = input.next();
    if(exit.equals("stop"){
        sum = Price * Kilograms;
        System.out.printf("Total price is %d\n", sum);
    }
}
while(!exit.equals("stop");
```

Comment: The D in your `do-while` needs to be lowercase. Also fix the indentation.